# Android 4.3 BTLE as server: How to start advertisements?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to implement a BTLE SERVER on the Nexus 7 with the new BTLE API in 4.3. I am running into several problems. First there are no examples with the SDK. The only example is for a client. Second, the documentation actually tells you to do the wrong thing. It states that one must use the `BluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy() with a BluetoothProfile.GATT_SERVER` parameter to obtain the `BluetoothGattServer` object. This approach will work, but one will be unable to link one's implementation of the `BluetoothGattServerCallback` to the BLE stack. (This callback is how one responds to client read and write requests among other things.) However, after stumbling on issue 58582 a developer pointed to the new `BluetoothManager.openGattServer()` method which takes your callback as a parameter and returns a `BluetoothGattServer` object. Well, one problem solved.

The next issue is more problematic. The `BluetoothGattServer` documentation states that one can use this class to create and advertise Bluetooth LE services and characteristics. Creating the services, etc. was not problem but they neglect to say how to start advertising. There is no method in the class itself or any other of the classes that I can find.

Does anyone know how to do this? At the moment all I can see is to use the same approach as used by the client, but that approach involves scanning (which is not advertising). All the documentation further suggests that the `BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan()` IS indeed JUST for scanning.

So how do I invoke advertisements once all my services, characteristics, and descriptors are in place?

Comment: I was searching for this function too. Unfortunately I don't know if this feature is supported since doc says that Android can act as a Central device and not a Peripheral. Anyway I didn't find any official statement saying that Android can not act as a Peripheral

Comment: I thought the documentation at least for BTLE said the reverse, that it COULD act as a server (it has the BluetoothGattServer class and the ability to construct Services, Characteristics, and Descriptors!) Actually it does. I know that the classic Bluetooth can only act as a client.

Comment: I'm wondering why Google didn't decide to give Peripheral feature to their Android devices. Apple gave that feature since iOS 6. Let's wait for other releases hoping to see this function :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As I understand, the Android implementation can only act as a central device, and not as a peripheral device. In Bluetooth Low Energy, only the peripheral can advertise. The central device can scan for advertisements from peripherals, and send connect requests as replies to (some kinds of) advertisements, to create a connection to the peripheral.

In BLE, there is a distinction between the concepts *Central/Peripheral* and *Server/Client*:

- Central/Peripheral is relating to the network architecture, where the central is the hub in a star, with one or more peripherals connected to it. It will typically be a phone, tablet or computer. A peripheral device can only connect to one central at a time.
- Server/Client (GATT server/client) is a higher level concept, related to the data that are kept in the devices and possibly communicated over the connection. Both central and peripheral devices can implement a GATT server and a GATT client, but is not required to have both.

So to answer your question: You cannot invoke advertisements. You will have to start scanning for peripheral devices to be able to make a connection to one or more of them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So this statement in the Android BluetoothGattServer class is incorrect?  Public API for the Bluetooth GATT Profile server role.

This class provides Bluetooth GATT server role functionality, allowing applications to create and advertise Bluetooth Smart services and characteristics.

BluetoothGattServer is a proxy object for controlling the Bluetooth Service via IPC. Use getProfileProxy(Context, BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener, int) to get the BluetoothGatt proxy object.

Comment: So in a nutshell, the answer you give is not what I want to hear and I hope its not true, but it may be and they just have misled us in their documentation (note that the same documentation also gives the wrong way to get the object!)

Comment: I think they might have been a bit quick in their documentation, yes. A peripheral device can put information about the services it has in the advertisement packets, i.e. advertise its services. For any peripheral to be able to know what services the central implements, it will do a service discovery procedure once connected. For more information about GATT and services, register at bluetooth.org and download the Core specification V4.0, and have a look at Volume 3 part G.

Comment: Unfortunately I got word from Google that you are correct. The documentation had a very poor choice of words and clearly needs work. I wasted two days configuring services, characteristics, etc for a device that I can't use. It was the word 'advertise' that threw me. We have implemented a BTLE stack that runs on PCs and it would have been good to have this stack to test against our clients. Now we can only do the reverse

Answer (score 12):

You will need API Level 21.

```
import android.bluetooth.le;
...
...
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
BluetoothLeAdvertiser myBluetoothLeAdvertiser =  myBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser ();
myBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising (AdvertiseSettings settings, AdvertiseData advertiseData, AdvertiseCallback callback);
```

Useful link is : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html

Comment: And the hardware support as well. Probably only in N6 and N9.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the `getProfileProxy` does not respond to the `GATT` or `GATT_SERVER` request. The API suggests advertising support, [but there is no code implemented behind yet.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58098) (Android Issue Tracker)

Same half-way implemented APIs were released initially when NFC was introduced and Google iterated adding more well rounded functionality with follow-up releases.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, BLE advertising ability (aka peripheral mode) will be added to Android with the upcoming version 4.4.3 of Kitkat. 
It's supposed to be released next week, but the changelog has already been leaked accidentially, see Google cache or [here](https://gist.github.com/archon810/1b7c6faa2e2eab831017) in line 2554: **peripheral mode (3/4): Add peripheral mode API**.

I guess we will know more soon.

Comment: Following your link, I could not help but notice a lot of instances of this: DO NOT MERGE BLE peripheral mode. This probably mean they are not ready for peripheral mode.