# Android: Bluetooth LE onLeScan() is not called

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am Creating an application availing BLE for API 18 or higher.I have implemented BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallBack methode but ;bluetootAdppter.StartLeScan(this)' is not calling @override onLeScan(.. , .. ,..) methode.I have searched across whole google but none solution has solved my problem yet.Please Help me
I have Tested this on SamsungGrand 2 and Samsung NOTE3 ..Thanks

```
public class DeviceScanActivity extends Activity implements BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback 
{
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
    // private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> alBlDevices;
    private ArrayList<String> alDevicesNames;
    BluetoothDevice tmpDevice;
    LinearLayout lllist;

    private BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_scan);
        initData();
        initUI();
    }

    private void initData() {
        bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        mHandler = new Handler();
        alBlDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

    }

    private void initUI() {
        lllist = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llList);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "initUI()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        scanLeDevice(true);

    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "START SCANNING",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.

            /*
             * mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             * 
             * @Override public void run() { mScanning = false;
             * mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
             * 
             * } }, SCAN_PERIOD);
             */

            mScanning = true;

            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(this);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] f) 
    {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HHHHH>", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        tmpDevice = device;

        alBlDevices.add(tmpDevice);
        alDevicesNames.add(tmpDevice.getName());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "scanning>" + tmpDevice.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View tvView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tv_single_device, null);
                ((TextView) tvView.findViewById(R.id.textView1))
                        .setText(alDevicesNames.get(alDevicesNames.size() - 1));
                lllist.addView(tvView);
                Log.v("Tag", tmpDevice.getName());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

..

logCat:

```
    05-08 10:46:06.373: E/ViewSystem(7019): ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.
05-08 10:46:06.443: D/dalvikvm(7019): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 707K, 34% free 9276K/13920K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
05-08 10:46:06.468: D/BluetoothAdapter(7019): startLeScan(): null
05-08 10:46:06.483: D/BluetoothAdapter(7019): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=4
05-08 10:46:06.528: D/libEGL(7019): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
05-08 10:46:06.533: I/(7019): PLATFORM VERSION : JB-MR-2
05-08 10:46:06.548: D/mali_winsys(7019): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
05-08 10:46:06.563: D/OpenGLRenderer(7019): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: please provide more information in logcat . which device are you running?? in logcat you will get startLeScan log

Comment: @mcd I have tested on Grand2 and and samsung note 3

Comment: please don't call startLeScan() more then two times from your log i found that LE Scan has already started . in grand2 scanning takes time. and check whether ble device is on (ble server).

Comment: i can't get it that how to check whether ble device is on (ble server).can you send me link of some tutorial? bluetooth is on on both devices note3 and grand 2. and i have validated that bluetooth enable disable validation  also in athor activity

Comment: I hve updated my call removed extra call to lescan() but still no result

Comment: you cannot create right now a android mob as server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128280/android-4-3-btle-as-server-how-to-start-advertisements

Answer (score 0):

you need implement the callback for your onLEScan which functionality returns the BLE device found you need to do something like mBluetoothAdapter.startLEScan(MyBLECallback) and implement the behavior for that BLE callback, it's like implementing the result from a separate thread, Regards

Note: passing the argument "this" will never work

Comment: I have already done it. reason why it is not working is that there is no such functionality yet available to make any device as a BLE Server.Thanks for your help. so i did it using hybrid combination.